# Why is the the rate of a reaction measured in concentration?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why is the rate of a reaction measured using concentration against time, rather than mol against time?

Comment: Because maybe the differential rate laws are in form of concentration. For 1st order kinetics it doesnt matter.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, because if you used an absolute amount (moles, for instance), by changing the quantity of reagents used, you couldn't use the existing data (or you would still need the volumes, to calculate the concentrations, in order to scale up/down the existing data, and fit them with your reaction).

Since the kinetics doesn't change with volumes, but with concentrations (for instance, if you use the same concentrations of reagents in 100 ml, or in 1 liter, the reaction, at least in theory, doesn't change) it's much easier and useful to express it in terms of concentrations.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you use concentration, you are taking in account of the reactant's abundance in the solution or mixture. This is compounded by the fact that the rate equation is also written in terms of a constant and powers of the concentration of reactants.